# Найти проблему в предложенном тексте

Tags: анализ-текста

Я считаю, что это "**Проблема красоты в жизни человека, в чем она проявляется?**"
Правильно ли это?

(1)Рано утром впотьмах под­ни­мал­ся я и брёл к элек­трич­ке, ехал в бит­ком на­би­том ва­го­не. (2)Потом — сля­кот­ный пер­рон... (З)Го­род­ские зим­ние угрю­мые су­мер­ки. (4)Люд­ской поток несёт тебя ко входу в метро. (5)Там давка: в две­рях, у тур­ни­ке­тов, у эс­ка­ла­то­ров, в под­зем­ных пе­ре­хо­дах. (6)В жёлтом элек­три­че­ском свете течёт и течёт мол­ча­ли­вая люд­ская река...

(7)К ве­че­ру на­гля­дишь­ся, на­слу­ша­ешь­ся, уста­нешь, еле бредёшь.

(8)Снова — метро, его под­зе­ме­лья... (9)Вы­бе­решь­ся от­ту­да, вздохнёшь и спе­шишь к элек­трич­ке, в её ве­чер­нюю тол­кот­ню, Бога моля, чтобы не от­ме­ни­ли.

(10)Так и текла моя мос­ков­ская жизнь: за днём — день, за не­де­лей — дру­гая. (11)За­тем­но вста­нешь, за­тем­но к дому прибьёшься. (12)Ни­че­му не рад, даже зиме и снегу.

(13)Уже пошёл де­кабрь, спеша к но­во­го­дью...

(14)Од­на­ж­ды ве­че­ром мне по­вез­ло вдвой­не: элек­трич­ку не от­ме­ни­ли и вагон ока­зал­ся не боль­но на­би­тым. (15)Усел­ся, га­зе­ту раз­вер­нул. (16)Хотя чего там вы­чи­ты­вать: убили, взо­рва­ли, огра­би­ли... (17)Ве­чер­ний поезд, уста­лые люди. (18)3има, тес­но­та, из там­бу­ра дует, кто-то вор­чит...

(19)Глаза при­крыл, но за­дре­мать не успел: за­стре­ко­та­ли рядом мо­ло­день­кие де­вуш­ки. (20)Хо­ро­шо, что об­хо­ди­лись без убо­го­го «ко­ро­че», «при­коль­но». (21)Обыч­ная де­ви­чья бол­тов­ня: лек­ции, прак­ти­ка, зачёты —сло­вом, учёба. (22)Потом Новый год вспом­ни­ли, ведь он не­да­ле­ко.

(23)— По­дар­ки пора по­ку­пать, — ска­за­ла одна из них. (24)— А чего да­рить? (25)И всё до­ро­го.
(26)— Ты ещё по­дар­ки не при­го­то­ви­ла?! — ужас­ну­лась дру­гая дев­чуш­ка. (27)— Когда же ты успе­ешь?!
(28)— А ты?
(29)— Ой, у меня почти всё го­то­во. (30)Маме я ещё осе­нью, когда в Ким­рах была, ку­пи­ла до­маш­ние та­поч­ки на вой­ло­ке, ста­ри­чок про­да­вал. (31)Руч­ная ра­бо­та, не­до­ро­го. (32)У ма­моч­ки ноги болят. (33)А там — вой­лок. (34)Ой, как мама об­ра­ду­ет­ся! — голос её про­зве­нел такой ра­до­стью, слов­но ей самой по­да­ри­ли что-то очень хо­ро­шее.

(35)Я го­ло­ву под­нял, взгля­нул: обыч­ная мо­ло­день­кая де­вуш­ка. (36)Лицо живое, милое, го­ло­сок, как ко­ло­коль­чик, зве­нит.
(37)— А папе... (38)У нас такой папа хо­ро­ший, ра­бо­тя­щий... (39)И я ему по­да­рю... (40)А де­душ­ке... (41)А ба­буш­ке...

(42)Не толь­ко я и со­се­ди, но, ка­жет­ся, уже весь вагон слу­шал счаст­ли­вую по­весть де­вуш­ки о но­во­год­них по­дар­ках. (43)На­вер­ное, у всех, как и у меня, от­сту­пи­ло, за­бы­лось днев­ное, не­слад­кое, а просну­лось, на­хлы­ну­ло иное, ведь и вправ­ду Новый год бли­зок...

(44)Я вышел из ва­го­на с лёгким серд­цем, то­ро­пить­ся не стал, про­пус­кая спе­ша­щих. (45)До­ро­га слав­ная: берёзы да сосны сто­ро­жат тро­пин­ку; не боль­но хо­лод­но, а на душе вовсе тепло. (46)Спа­си­бо той де­воч­ке, ко­то­рую унес­ла элек­трич­ка. (47)А в по­мощь ей — ма­ли­но­вый чи­стый закат над чёрными елями, бор­мо­чу­щая во тьме ре­чуш­ка под гиб­ким де­ре­вян­ным мост­ком, говор вдали, дет­ский смех и, ко­неч­но, на­деж­да. (48)Так что шагай, че­ло­ве­че...

Comment: Я не вижу, что именно Вы нашли - и в чем вообще вопрос. Постарайтесь переформулировать более понятно. Иначе ваш вопрос быстро окажется среди предлагаемых к удалению.

Comment: В самом верху, Проблема красоты в жизни человека, в чем она проявляется? Такая проблема поднята в тексте?

Comment: Т.е. задание было в том, чтобы указать проблему, поднимаемую в предложенном тексте? Если да, то я исправил заголовок и сам вопрос. Посмотрите. Не надо это объяснять в комментариях, надо править вопрос, если говорят, что он непонятен.

Comment: Сообществу. Придумайте нормальную метку. У меня ничего умнее не получилось.

Comment: то есть проблема правильная?

Comment: Какая проблема? Вы можете внятно сформулировать, ответ на какой вопрос Вы хотите получить. Здесь не справочное бюро, вопросы и ответы должны иметь какую-то ценность и для последующих посетителей. А я даже метки придумать не смог, ибо не знаю, о чем вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Проблемы красоты не вижу.

Вижу другие:
1. Проблема восприятия окружающего мира человеком;

2.проблема внимательного, заботливого отношения к родным и близким;

3. проблема умения радоваться, (проблема источника радости);

Или так: Как много нужно человеку для того, чтобы быть счастливым? Что необходимо каждому из нас, чтобы окружающий мир стал добрее, светлее, лучше? Умеем ли мы ценить то, что имеем? Публицист Б.П.Екимов предлагает читателям подумать о том, почему люди разучились радоваться жизни.

Answer (score 0):

Я написал: "Влияние интенсивного темпа жизни на человека". Про красоту вряд ли

Comment: Вы сам себя опровергаете? Странно... Что-то я совсем Вас не понимаю.